# Why does `.` and `..` have different inode numbers inside `/` on a Mac?

Tags: c, macos, filesystems

I was playing around with implementing my own `pwd` command. To find the entire path, I need to traverse the `inode` tree until I reach the root, and the way to tell that I've hit the root is by checking for equal `inode` numbers stored for `.` and `..`.

But on my Mac that seems to not be case, at least if you look at this table below.

```
    dirent |       stat | link to
-----------+------------+--------
  34078072 |   34078072 | self
  31103058 |   31103058 | parent
  31103058 |   31103058 | self
  31103020 |   31103020 | parent
  31103020 |   31103020 | self
    613497 |     613497 | parent
    613497 |     613497 | self
    603204 |     603204 | parent
    603204 |     603204 | self
    157433 |     157433 | parent
    157433 |     157433 | self
         2 |          2 | parent
         2 |          2 | self   // This is root aka /
         1 |          2 | parent // There is something above it?
```

This was generated using the code below. The `stat` struct seems to be doing fine, but `dirent` has a different value when it comes to `/`. Why is that the case? Shouldn't `dirent` and `stat` have the same values for inode number? Why is it different on a Mac?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void inodes();

int main()
{
    printf("    dirent |       stat | link to\n");
    printf("-----------+------------+--------\n");
    inodes();
    return 0;
}

void inodes()
{
    DIR* directory = opendir(".");
    struct dirent* entry = NULL;
    struct stat status;
    ino_t self = -1;
    ino_t parent = -1;

    while ((entry = readdir(directory))) {
        stat(entry->d_name, &status);
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0) {
            self = status.st_ino;
            printf("%10.llu | %10.llu | self\n", entry->d_ino, self);
        }
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
            parent = status.st_ino;
            printf("%10.llu | %10.llu | parent\n", entry->d_ino, parent);
        }
    }
    if (self != parent) {
        if (chdir("..") != -1) {
            inodes();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After checking the return value for `stat`, it's `0` all the way through, so there's no error there.

Comment: This might be related to the fact that in the HFS file system, the root folder has the file ID 2 and the parent ID 1. (See e.g. http://dubeiko.com/development/FileSystems/HFSPLUS/tn1150.html, I could not find that on the Apple website anymore.)

Comment: @MartinR your comment might be the answer, but I'm having trouble finding anything about file ID 1 and 2 in that document you linked. Could you elaborate a tiny bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Macintosh HFS+ file system, every file and folder has a unique
"file ID". This file system is described in Apple's
["Technical Note TN1150 – HFS Plus Volume Format"](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html).

In particular, the root folder *always* has the file ID 2 and the parent
ID 1. In the TN1150, these are documented as

```
enum {
    kHFSRootParentID            = 1,
    kHFSRootFolderID            = 2,
    ...
}

kHFSRootParentID
    Parent ID of the root folder.
kHFSRootFolderID
    Folder ID of the root folder.
```

The inode on a HFS+ file system reflects exactly
the file ID. This might explain why `readdir()` reports the inode
`2` for the "." entry of the root folder, and the inode `1` for
the ".." entry of the root folder. (But I do not have a definite reference for this fact. One could try to find the source code at
http://www.opensource.apple.com :)

On the other hand, ".." in the root folder is always a link to the
root folder itself. Therefore, when

```
stat(entry->d_name, &status);
```

is executed for the ".." entry, a `stat()` on the root folder is done,
so this gives the inode `2` again.